# How to rotate Apple map in driving direction in ios?

Tags: ios, mapkit

I want to rotate apple map based on user's driving direction,
Any idea or solution to rotate map like that way?

I can collect array of last 5-10 moved location, but based on it, Can I calculate heading or anything else to rotate map?

Comment: `isRotateEnabled = true`, `userTrackingMode = .followWithHeading`, and perhaps `showsUserLocation = true` look like the things you'd need to set on `MKMapView` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapview

Comment: Actually, I want to rotate map manually as I want to rotate maps in few conditions only

Comment: Cool. Without knowing more re: your code, the vars above are the ones you'll likely need to manipulate to accomplish what you want to do. The other thing you could do is get the last 5-10 coordinates from your location manager and calculate your heading based on the first and last coordinate in the array slice.

Comment: Is there any way to rotate map with direction arrow like apple navigation map does?